# Why $\prod_{i\in I} \Bbb Z$ is not a projective $\Bbb Z$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $\Bbb Z$ be the ring of integers and $I$ a non-countable index set. Why $$\prod_{i\in I} \Bbb Z$$ is not a projective $\Bbb Z$-module?

Comment: Could this not follow from Kaplansky's Theorem for modules?

Comment: The fact that $I$ is non-countable is superfluous: you can reduce the problem to the countable case!

Comment: @YACP Absolutely it is a duplicate; $\mathbb Z$-modules are free iff projective.